# XamarinIOS RestAPI request System.NullReferenceException

Tags: ios, rest, http, xamarin, https

The app is just a tester trying to grab data from a service on another machine. I had made something previously using the same function which worked so im unsure what the issue is.

Seems to work fine on Android but porting to IOS and running request fails.

this is the request call

```
 ExampleList = await App.DataService.GetAllAsync<example>();
```

grabs the DataService (IP used is different but i know it works on android):

```
public partial class App : Application

    {
        static DataService dataService;
        public static DataService DataService
        {
            get
            {
                if (dataService == null)
                {   //i know this isnt my ip
                    dataService = new DataService("http://###.###.#.###:5001")  
                    .AddEntityModelEndpoint<example>("api/examples");
                }
                return dataService;
            }
        }
```

Goes to the data service and use the insecure handler because i dont have proper https certs . This could be an issue but the ip calling is only http and again still works on android both as https and http.

```
    public class DataService

    {

        private HttpClient client;

        private Dictionary<string, string> modelEndpoints;

        private string UrlAddress;



        public DataService(string APIipAddress) //base ip address of api

        {



#if DEBUG                                          // V need dependency injection                        // V crash on here ios
            HttpClientHandler insecureHandler = DependencyService.Get<IHttpClientHandlerService>().GetInsecureHandler(); // insecure SSL certificate handler to HttpClient (only in debug)

            client = new HttpClient(insecureHandler);

#else

            this.client = new HttpClient();

#endif

            UrlAddress = APIipAddress; // set RESTful ip address for web api

            modelEndpoints = new Dictionary<string, string>(); //  endpoints dictionary (each model class in service)

        }
```

The error is as shown (Doesn't display the full error! ):

```
    StackTrace  "  at App2.Data.DataService..ctor (System.String APIipAddress) [0x00008] in /Users/mac/Desktop/Test/App2/App2/App2/Data/DataService.cs:23 \n  at App2.App.get_DataService () [0x0000e] in /Users/mac/Desktop/Test/App2/App2/App2/App.xaml.cs:20 \n  at App2.ViewModels.…"   string
```

I have jumped a few Xam versions so maybe this setup needs adapting for IOS.

I was considering getting HTTPS certs though I'm not sure if it would fix this issue before I go to that option.

I saw some issues regarding info.plist and NSAppTransportSecurity but i have also added that and NSAllowArbitraryLoads < unsure if this is something required but i am also using a different version of ios, vs and Xam than previously

Comment: 99% this `DependencyService.Get<IHttpClientHandlerService>()` is returning null

Comment: You need to check the ios implementation of `GetInsecureHandler` via DependencyService. For more details about the DependencyService on ios, please check the docs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction#implement-the-interface-on-each-platform